How to convince PHP that it is redirectly correctly
I have created a function in a customised Wordpress settings page that fetches products from an API. There are a lot of results and it takes a long time, so if I try to fetch them all at once it takes too long and times out.  So I have now set it up to get only 1 page of 100 results at a time and there are (for now) 26 pages of results to fetch.
So, the idea is to load the page with a parameter of "page_to_process=1" and when the page sees that "$_GET['page_to_process']" exists, it runs the function that fetches that page number.  That function then uses the 'header' function to redirect back to the same page but with the "page_to_process" parameter iterated by 1 so that it will then get the next page of results and so on, until such time as $results is empty then it returns to the page with the parameter removed and ceases the running of the script.
Here's the code:
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['page_to_process']) && $_GET['page_to_process'] != ''){
  gd_sync_products($_GET['page_to_process']));
}

function gd_sync_products($page){
  $api_credentials = api_credentials();
  if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'get_products'){
      $page=1;
  }
  $products=array();
  $results = gd_get_products($api_credentials['username'],$api_credentials['password'],$api_credentials['baseURL'],$api_credentials['version'],$api_credentials['format'],$page);
  $arrayData = json_decode($results, true);
  $page_count = $arrayData['page_count'];
  $productData = $arrayData['data'];
  $products = array_merge($products, $productData);
  $page++;
  if($page > $arrayData['page_count']){
      $url_parameter = '';
  } else {
      $url_parameter = '&page_to_process=' . $page;
  }

  foreach($products as $product){
      // DOES STUFF WITH THE PRODUCTS
  }

  $redirect_url = get_site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=api-settings' . $url_parameter;

  header('Location: ' . $redirect_url); 
}
?>

The problem now is that after a while, the page thinks that it's stuck in an infinite loop and gives a "Page is redirecting incorrectly" error.  It does this after it's retrieved about 20 pages of results, so is just falling a little short.  But ideally, I need it to be able to carry on for as long as is needed, even if there were 50 pages of results to get.
Any suggestions?

Why not load results as they're needed (pagination or infinite scroll)? Instead of automatically loading results.

Because you see in my code where it says "DOES STUFF WITH THE PRODUCTS" - what this actually then does is it creates WooCommerce products in the site database from the data it's retrieved.  So this whole thing is to synchronize products from a suppliers API into WooCommerce and then on a daily basis it will need to then update stock levels for all products from the API and add any new products and remove discontinued products, etc.

try to do the import in background with wp-cron : https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/

I do intend to also set it up as a cron, but I also want to be able to run it on demand.

An error may occur while processing page 20
You can check the php_error log or enable error display by adding the following line of code before the code:
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

For the header() function, if any message is displayed before calling the function (e.g. error), it will not run.
